# Weird order with arabic text with numbers

Tags: text, web, localization, numbers, arabic

I have a code for a class management system.

from web-browsers I see

```
Case 1: 101عرب-2
```

but in my mssql db, this actually is

```
Case 2: عرب-2#d#101 (remove #d#)
```

I'm not really sure how it has been stored, 
but at least, SQL Manager shows me like that.
English version of this code is

```
101ARB-2
```

How can I show the code like case 2, not like case 1?

**added:**

Since the data above is from my client, so I'm not really sure,
but I strongly believe that the insert statement would have been like Case 2

```
Insert tbl(code) values (N'عرب-2#d#101')
```

again, please remove #d#, when you read the code in this page.
I even don't know how to type like Case 2. :(
If you don't get me, just try to copy Case 2 and delete 'd' in the middle of #s.

**added:**

I've added the image of the real Case 2.

[image: this is what I want to get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in order to control the way bi-directional text is displayed, you need to use  direction control characters:

- U+202A:   LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING (LRE)
- U+202B:   RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING (RLE)
- U+202D:   LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE (LRO)
- U+202E:   RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (RLO)
- U+202C:   POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (PDF)

However, since you mentioned the web page, it may make sense to use `<bdo>` element to control the text behavior.
Whatever solution you want to use, it is more like localization question.

To learn more about Arabic localization, you can refer to the following W3C articles:

- [Creating HTML Pages in Arabic, Hebrew and Other Right-to-left Scripts](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/)
- [Unicode controls vs. markup for bidi support](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-controls)
- [Inline markup and bidirectional text in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/)

Comment: <bdo dir="rtl">101عرب-2</bdo> or <bdi>101عرب-2</bdi> were the solution. Thanks for your help!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to collate, if you want to store native language character, define your db column as nvarchar, nchar datatype. Then while inserting prefix the letter N'your value'. This will store the value same as that of native text.

Insert into table values(N'101عرب-2')

Comment: It has nothing to do with collation, but with [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/). Certain characters have strong direction and that's basically the reason it was shown that way. Collation is OK, otherwise characters would be corrupted.

Comment: yeah i agree with you.. I said about entire database context to store and retrive. To store unicode you need follow the step which i mentioned.